# Dask's slow compute performance on single core

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I have implemented a map function that parses strings into an XML tree, traverses this tree and extracts some information. A lot of if-then-else stuff, no additional IO code.

The speedup we got from Dask was not very satisfying, so we took a closer look at the raw execution performance on a single but large item (580 MB of XML string) in a single partition.

Here's the code:

```
def timedMap(x):
  start = time.time()
  # computation, no IO or access to Dask variables, no threading or multiprocessing
  ...
  return time.time() - start

print("Direct Execution")
print(timedMap(xml_string))

print("Dask Distributed")
import dask
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client(threads_per_worker=1, n_workers=1)
print(client.submit(timedMap, xml_string).result())
client.close()

print("Dask Multiprocessing")
import dask.bag as db
bag = db.from_sequence([xml_string], npartitions=1)
print(bag.map(timedMap).compute()[0])
```

The output (that's the time without before/after overhead) is:

```
Direct Execution
54.59478211402893
Dask Distributed
91.79525017738342
Dask Multiprocessing
86.94628381729126
```

I've repeated this many times. It seems that Dask has not only an overhead for communication and task management, but the individual computation steps are also significantly slower as well.

Why is the computation inside Dask so much slower? I suspected the profiler and increased the profiling interval from 10 to 1000ms, which knocked of 5 seconds. But still... Then I suspected memory pressure, but the worker doesn't reach it's limit, not even the 50%.

In terms of overhead (measuring total times submit+result and map+compute), Dask adds 18 seconds for the distributed case and 3 seconds for the multiprocessing case. I'm happy to pay this overhead, but I don't like that the actual computation takes so much longer. Do you have a clue why this would be the case? What can I tweak to speed this up?

Note: when I double the compute load, all durations roughly double as well.

All the best,
Boris

Comment: There is some overhead in using dask compared with direct execution but 18secs does seem large.  Can I ask you to generate a performance report: https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/diagnosing-performance.html#performance-reports

Comment: Well, 18 secs is only the overhead before and after the actual computation. But since the pure computation also takes 32 secs longer (and that's what bugs me most), the total overhead is 50 seconds for a 55 second task!

Here is the report: http://www.borislau.de/dask-report.html
timedMap takes 88.79 secs on the first page, in the worker profile it's 75.5 (why the difference?). The whole thing takes 99 secs wall clock time. All of this is really slow compared to the 54.5 secs that the direct execution takes.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't expect any speedup because you have only a single partition.

You should expect some slowdown because you're moving 500MB across processes in Python.  I recommend that you read the following: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/best-practices.html#load-data-with-dask

Comment: I use a single partition for debugging purposes only. If you look at the timedMap function defined above, you'll see that the compute time is measured within this function, and thus without the time required for moving the data between processes! And I would expect this to be similar to the direct execution time, but it's not...